# $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$ is not a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, factoring, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I know that the ring  $R=\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$ is not a field but an integral domain as you can easily show with Eisenstein criterion that $(xy-z^2)$ is an irreducible polynomial. Now I don't understand, why the irreducibility does not imply that $R$ is a field, because in other quotient rings I've seen before it was enough to show that " $I$ is irreducible then $R/I$ is a field ". Why here not? How can I show that $R$ is not a field here? Do I have to find a bigger Ideal than $(xy-z^2)$ in order to show that $(xy-z^2)$ is not maximal? I don't see any simpler way.

Comment: You mean $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$?

Comment: " Do I have to find a bigger Ideal than (xy−z^2) in order to show that (xy−z^2) is not maximal?" This will work.

Comment: One thing to know is that for $k$ a field then $k[t]$ is a PID (every ideal is principal) so that $f$ irreducible implies $(f)$ is a prime and maximal ideal, and that PID are very rare, for example $(x,y)$ is a non-principal ideal of $k[x,y]$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $R=A/I$, where $A$ is a commutative ring with $1\ne 0$, and $I$ is an ideal of $A$, then

- $R$ is an integral domain if and only if $I$ is a prime ideal.$\\[4pt]$

  $R$ is a field if and only if $I$ is a maximal ideal.

In the context of the current problem, let

- $A=k[x,y,z]$, where $k$ is a field.$\\[4pt]$

  $I=(xy-z^2)$.$\\[4pt]$

  $R=A/I$.

Since $A$ is a UFD and $xy-z^2$ is irreducible in $A$, it follows that $I$ is a prime ideal, hence $R$ is an integral domain.

To show that $R$ is not a field, it suffices to show that $I$ is not a maximal ideal.

But the ideal $M=(x,y,z)$ is clearly maximal, and we have $I\subseteq M$, hence it suffices to show $I\ne M$.

As an example, we have $z\in M$, but since $z$ is not a multiple of $xy-z^2$, it follows that $z\not\in I$.

Therefore $I\ne M$, so $I$ is not maximal, hence $R$ is not a field.

**Notes:**

Rings such as $\mathbb{Z}$ and $k[x]\;$(where $k$ is a field) are principal ideal domains (PIDs), i.e., integral domains such that every ideal is principal.

Since a PID is a UFD, every irreducible element is a prime element, and every prime element is irreducible.

In a PID, the maximal ideals are precisely the nonzero prime ideals, and an ideal is maximal if and only if it's a principal prime ideal (a principal ideal generated by a prime element).

But not all UFDs are PIDs. In particular, if $n > 1$, the ring $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ (where $k$ is a field) is a not a PID, since for example, the ideal $(x_1,...,x_n)$ is not principal.

Answer (score 3):

For an element $\;p\in\Bbb C[x,y,z]\;$ , let us denotes by $\;\overline p\;$ its image in the quotient ring $\;R:=\Bbb C[x,y,z]/\langle xy-z^2\rangle\;$.

Then for example, $\;\overline{xy}\neq0\in R\;$ , yet there is no $\;q\in \Bbb C[x,y,z]\;$ s.t. $\;\overline{xy}\cdot \overline q=\overline1\;$ , since that'd mean that

$$xyq-1\in\langle xy-z^2\rangle\subset\Bbb C[x,y,z]\iff xyq+(xy-z^2)h=1\,,\,\,\text{for some}\;h\in\Bbb C[x,y,z]\implies\;$$

substituting $\;z=0,\,y=1\;$ , that'd mean $\;x(q-h)=1\;$ . End now the argument.

Another way: show that $\;\langle xy-z^2\rangle\subsetneq \langle xy-z^2,\,x\rangle\;$

Comment: Why can you set $z=0$ and $y=1$ ? And why is $xq=xh+1$ a contradiction?

Comment: @Thesinus Yes, we can, and what you say is a contradiction because there is not multiplicative inverse to $\;x\;$ within $\;\Bbb C[x,y,z]\;$ (elementary proof)

Comment: Is the contradiction because of $q=h+1/x \notin R$? Still I don't understand why you randomly  choose z=0 and y=1?

Comment: @Thesinus I chose those values because then I get an almost trivial contradiction...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know that you chose them because of the trivial contradiction, I was just asking 'why' you can choose them? What gives you the permission? I thought that $x$, $y$ and $z$ can't be arbitrarily be defined! (now knowing indeed  they can...)

Comment: @Thesinus They're unknowns of a polynomial ring over the complex field: any substitution will make sense! If we have some *polynomial* equality $\;p=q\;$, then for **any** substitution of the unknowns by numerical values the equality remains as "functions". This is due to a rather obvious isomorphism between polynomials and polynomial functions (in any number of variables) over an infinite field (this is false if the field is not infinite!).

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbf C[x,y,z]$ is a U.F.D. (of Krull dimension $3$). As in all U.F.D.s, irreducible elements generate a prime ideal of height $1$, thus the quotient $\mathbf C[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$ is an integral domain of dimension $2$, and field has dimension $0$.